# MySQL - Order by on multiple left join

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the tables `ForumRooms`, `ForumTopics` and `ForumPosts`, they're pretty self explanatory.

At the moment I'm changing the query for the main forum rooms page to be able to get the last post time and user, stored in `ForumPosts`.

**Table Structure**

*ForumRooms*

```
|  id  |  title  |
|----------------|
|  1   | Room 1  |
|  2   | Room 2  |
```

*ForumThreads*

```
|  id  |  title    |  forum_room_id  |
|------------------|-----------------|
|  1   | Thread 1  |  1              |
|  2   | Thread 2  |  2              |
|  3   | Thread 3  |  1              |
```

*ForumPosts*

```
|  id  |  content  |  forum_thread_id |  post_time  |  user_id  |
|------------------|------------------|-------------|-----------|
|  1   | A post 1  |  1               |  15/02/2015 |  1        |
|  2   | A post 2  |  2               |  16/02/2015 |  2        |
|  3   | A post 3  |  1               |  17/02/2015 |  1        |
|  4   | A post 4  |  1               |  18/02/2015 |  2        |
```

**The Aim**

I'm trying to write 1 query to allow the following formatted output:

*Output*

```
|  ForumRoom  |  Thread Count  |  Post Count  |  Last Post Time  |  Last Post UserID  |
|-------------|----------------|--------------|------------------|--------------------|
|  Room 1     |  2             |  3           |  16/02/2015      |  2                 |
|  Room 2     |  1             |  1           |  18/02/2015      |  2                 |
```

**The Problem**

At the moment I can get everything in 1 query apart from the `Last Post Time` and `Last Post UserID`.

The below query should give what I need due to the `ORDER BY` on the `ForumPosts.id` but I think the `GROUP BY` prevents it from working as required.

```
SELECT ForumRooms.title, COUNT(DISTINCT ForumThreads.id), COUNT(ForumPosts.id), ForumPosts.post_time, ForumPosts.user_id
FROM ForumRooms
LEFT JOIN ForumThreads ON ForumRooms.id = ForumThreads.forum_room_id
LEFT JOIN ForumPosts ON ForumThreads.id = ForumPosts.forum_thread_id
GROUP BY ForumRooms.id
ORDER BY ForumPosts.id DESC
```

How can I adapt my query to get the last two missing pieces of data?

Comment: you can't order by joined table columns?

Comment: Aggregate value of subsets can usually be solved by either [sub-queries or rephrasing the question](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/03/14/how-to-find-the-max-row-per-group-in-sql-without-subqueries/).

Comment: The MySQL documentation about [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) explains why your query does not produce the results you expect. In fact, it is not even valid SQL; MySQL accepts it but the values it returns for `ForumPosts.post_time` and `ForumPosts.user_id` are indeterminate.

Comment: @axiac exactly, hence the asking of this question - they're there for a pseudo representation

Comment: Note that dates in SQL adhere to  a specific format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a good place to use the `substring()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT ForumRooms.title, COUNT(DISTINCT ForumThreads.id), COUNT(ForumPosts.id), 
       MAX(ForumPosts.post_time),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ForumPosts.user_id ORDER BY ForumPosts.post_time DESC), ',', 1)
FROM ForumRooms LEFT JOIN
     ForumThreads
     ON ForumRooms.id = ForumThreads.forum_room_id LEFT JOIN
     ForumPosts
     ON ForumThreads.id = ForumPosts.forum_thread_id
GROUP BY ForumRooms.id
ORDER BY ForumPosts.id DESC
```

Comment: Yep, and just in case one has a ridiculously large number of users posting, prefix it with (eg) `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;`

Comment: This works well but it seems to get confused if I add `SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ForumPosts.user_id ORDER BY ForumPosts.id DESC), ',', 1) as lastPostUserId, ` and then `LEFT JOIN user ON lastPostUserId = user.id`? The joined user doesn't match the id in the `lastPostUserId`

Comment: Found a solution to that issue: `(SELECT username FROM user WHERE id = (SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(forumPosts.userId ORDER BY forumPosts.id DESC), ',', 1)))`